# Attaching :id param to a GET request and returning User in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parameters, routes

I have a table in my app that shows a list of Users.

Using the `link_to` method, I want to be able to click a user's name, store a specific param of this user  as well as the `current_user` (the user that's logged in).

The user's name being clicked in the table should have it's :id param saved as well as the `current_user`'s id.

The page the `current_user` is routed to displays a form, that once submitted should create a new `Booking` object assigning the value passed in through a `text_area` called `notes` to the `:notes` field, and should assign the `user` and `current_user`'s :id params to two fields on the Booking model called `cleaner_id` and `host_id` respectively upon submission.

Here's what I've tried,

**In the routes.rb file:**
`get 'show_booking_form/:id', to: 'bookings#show', as: 'booking_form'`
This should route the user to the booking form. The booking form title should display the table user's name.

**Here's the table field that displays the table user:**
`<td><%= link_to "#{user.name}", booking_form_path(@user)  %></td>`
Upon being clicked, this needs to store two params
    1. The `current_user` id, (the logged in user doing the clicking)(host user)
    2. The `user` id, (the table user being clicked)(cleaner user)

Here's the bookings controller `show` action that defines a host and a cleaner
    `def show
    @host = current_user
    @cleaner = User.find(params[:id])
  end`

**Here's the page the user is routed to, containing a form with the cleaner users name as the title. This form should submit current_user and table users params as `host_id` and `cleaner_id`, respectively.**

```
<h1 style='text-align:center'>Book <%= @cleaner.name %> for a cleaning </h1>
<%= bootstrap_form_for create_booking_path do |f| %>
    <%= f.text_area :notes,
                    rows: 6,
                    minlength: 5,
                    maxlength: 1000,
                    placeholder: 'Leave a note for your cleaner!',
                    class: 'form-control' %>


    <%= f.submit "Book Now!", id:'client-btn', class: 'form-control btn btn-primary'  %>
    <% end %>
</div>
```

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: I get the following error: No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"bookings", :id=>nil}, missing required keys: [:id] . when trying to run the server.... I'm guessing theres an issue surrounding the way i'm handling params

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `routes.rb`, just do:

```
resources :bookings
```

Which will give you:

```
     bookings GET    /bookings(.:format)              bookings#index
              POST   /bookings(.:format)              bookings#create
  new_booking GET    /bookings/new(.:format)          bookings#new
 edit_booking GET    /bookings/:id/edit(.:format)     bookings#edit
      booking GET    /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#show
              PATCH  /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#update
              PUT    /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#update
              DELETE /bookings/:id(.:format)          bookings#destroy
```

Then, make this:

```
link_to "#{user.name}", booking_form_path(@user)
```

look something more like:

```
link_to @user.name, new_booking_path(cleaner_id: @user.id, host_id: current_user.id)
```

A couple of notes:

- This assumes you have `@user` available to you (you reference both `user` and `@user` - it's probably one or the other and is likely why you're getting the error you mention in your comment if `@user` is `nil` for some reason).
- No need to use string interpolation on `user.name`
- Extra key/value pairs included in your `new_booking_path` (or any path, for that matter), are appended to the url as query parameters and will show up in your `params`.
- Try to use the standard RESTful routes. There's little need for `booking_form` when that's what `new_booking_path` is for. Similarly, you don't need `create_booking_path` because you already have `bookings_path` which will route to your `create` action when you `POST` your form.

With this, you should see `:cleaner_id` and `:host_id` in the params for your `new` action when you click on the link.

Then, in your `new` action, do something like:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController 

  def new
    @cleaner    = User.find(params[:cleaner_id])
    @host       = current_user
    @booking    = Booking.new
  end

end
```

Now, in your form, you can do someting along the lines of:

```
<h1 style='text-align:center'>Book <%= @cleaner.name %> for a cleaning </h1>
<%= bootstrap_form_for @booking do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :notes,
                  rows: 6,
                  minlength: 5,
                  maxlength: 1000,
                  placeholder: 'Leave a note for your cleaner!',
                  class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :cleaner_id, value: @cleaner.id %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :host_id,    value: @host.id    %>

  <%= f.submit "Book Now!", id:'client-btn', class: 'form-control btn btn-primary'  %>
<% end %>
```

The `@cleaner_id` and `@host_id` are now hidden fields and will be submitted to and available in your `BookingController`'s `create` action. You might need to fiddle with that syntax a bit.

Honestly, I don't know why you're doing all that `host` business when `host` always resolves to `current_user`. But, I'm sure you have your reasons.

I think if I were you, I would do:

```
resources :cleaners do 
  resources :bookings, shallow: true 
end
```

Which will give you:

```
   cleaner_bookings GET    /cleaners/:cleaner_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#index
                    POST   /cleaners/:cleaner_id/bookings(.:format)          bookings#create
new_cleaner_booking GET    /cleaners/:cleaner_id/bookings/new(.:format)      bookings#new
       edit_booking GET    /bookings/:id/edit(.:format)                      bookings#edit
            booking GET    /bookings/:id(.:format)                           bookings#show
                    PATCH  /bookings/:id(.:format)                           bookings#update
                    PUT    /bookings/:id(.:format)                           bookings#update
                    DELETE /bookings/:id(.:format)                           bookings#destroy
           cleaners GET    /cleaners(.:format)                               cleaners#index
                    POST   /cleaners(.:format)                               cleaners#create
        new_cleaner GET    /cleaners/new(.:format)                           cleaners#new
       edit_cleaner GET    /cleaners/:id/edit(.:format)                      cleaners#edit
            cleaner GET    /cleaners/:id(.:format)                           cleaners#show
                    PATCH  /cleaners/:id(.:format)                           cleaners#update
                    PUT    /cleaners/:id(.:format)                           cleaners#update
                    DELETE /cleaners/:id(.:format)                           cleaners#destroy
```

If you don't want those `cleaners` paths, then just do:

```
resources :cleaners, only: [] do 
  resources :bookings, shallow: true 
end
```

Then:

```
link_to @user.name, new_cleaner_booking_path(@user)
```

Your controller:

```
class BookingsController < ApplicationController 

  def new
    @cleaner    = User.find(params[:cleaner_id])
    @booking    = Booking.new
  end

end
```

And your form:

```
<h1 style='text-align:center'>Book <%= @cleaner.name %> for a cleaning </h1>
<%= bootstrap_form_for [@cleaner, @booking] do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_area :notes,
                  rows: 6,
                  minlength: 5,
                  maxlength: 1000,
                  placeholder: 'Leave a note for your cleaner!',
                  class: 'form-control' %>

  <%= f.submit "Book Now!", id:'client-btn', class: 'form-control btn btn-primary'  %>
<% end %>
```

Now you should have `cleaner_id` in your `create` action and you can use `current_user` as your `host`